# Create new column based on text condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make new column based on another columns with text

Let say, I have this column

```
    Name
Acer aspire 1
Acer spin
Dell alienware
Dell 2-in-1
MSI thin
Asus flip
MSI flip
```

to be like this

```
    Name           touchscreen
Acer aspire 1     No
Acer spin         Yes
Dell alienware    No
Dell 2-in-1       Yes
MSI thin          No
Asus flip         Yes
MSI flip          Yes
```

and the condition is, if in the column consist "spin", "2-in-1", "flip", then it is yes, but if it isn't, then it is no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), for regex `or` is used `|`:

```
df['touchscreen'] = np.where(df['Name'].str.contains('spin|flip|2-in-1'), 'Yes', 'No')
print (df)
             Name touchscreen
0   Acer aspire 1          No
1       Acer spin         Yes
2  Dell alienware          No
3     Dell 2-in-1         Yes
4        MSI thin          No
5       Asus flip         Yes
6        MSI flip         Yes
```

Comment: Thanks, for helping me. I'm new in this world programming, so still need learn much more